# ¿Cómo configurar Archivo de propiedades en HikariCP?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, archivo-de-propiedades

Necesito ayuda con HikariCP, al intentar configurarlo mediante un archivo properties [(es posible según su pagina en GitHub)](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) simplemente no funciona, adjunto el código:

```
public class DatabaseManager {

private DatabaseClient[] databaseClients;
private HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

public DatabaseManager(String absoluteFilePath) {
    final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig(absoluteFilePath);
    this.hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);


 // devuelve null u-u
    System.out.println(hikariConfig.getUsername()); 


   }
}
```

Archivo 'hikaricp.properties':

```
## Database Settings
dataSourceClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource
dataSource.user=root
dataSource.password=
dataSource.databaseName=imagine-db
dataSource.portNumber=3306
dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

Comment: Hola @KrozT. Por favor indica la versión de HikariCP que utilizas. Dependiendo de eso, cambiará la estructura de tu archivo properties.

Comment: Te es posible configurarlo de otra manera? Con una instancia de `HikariConfig` aplicando directamente tus parámetros de conexión, has probado con ello?

Comment: Nunca he usado Hikari, pero si sigues el source code, notaras que las propiedades que lee del archivo las carga en la propiedad `HikariConfig.getDatsourceProperties()`.  Así que sí las carga correctamente, pero por alguna razón, que asumo es "by design", no hace set de los valores correspondientes en el objeto config.

Comment: Mas tarde el constructor de `HikariDataSource` copia también, via reflection, los `dataSourceProperties` y asumo que eso es lo que usa para crear conexiones. Me parece un diseño desagradable, pero luce como asi es como funciona.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Pero si acá ni siquiera es error de hikari sino de la carga del archivo. Sin un stacktrace, esta pregunta no sirve

Answer (score 1):

La configuración de HikariCP depende mucho de la versión de Tomcat y el gestor que uses. En Tomcat8 por ejemplo funciona poniendo en el fichero de propiedades:

```
dataSource.username=username
dataSource.password=
```

Si esto no funciona, otra de las opciones es definirlo a nivel de configuración y no a nivel de DataSource, es decir:

```
username=username
password=
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.